# the default row to choose for the same max values

Tags: azure-data-explorer

If I have the following sample data:

| Name | Number | Stage | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 120 | start | pending |
| A1 | 120 | finished | closed |
| A2 | 100 | finished | closed |

If I use | summarize arg_max(Number, Stage) by Name, Which row will be chosen.

Any document mentioned this mechanism？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be decided by the [row order policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/roworderpolicy) on the table, pertinent part here:

> The row order policy sets the preferred arrangement of rows within an
> extent. The policy is optional and set at the table level.

You can check how it is ordered currently with the following command.

`.show table [TableName] policy reworder`

In addition to this [ingestion time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/ingestiontimepolicy) may be useful to check on your table by using the scalar function [`ingestion_time()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ingestiontimefunction?pivots=azuredataexplorer) to see if this offers a suitable way to pick the most recent and maximum event:

```
T
| extend IngestionTime = ingestion_time()
| summarize arg_max(IngestionTime, Number) by Name
```

Comment: I tried ingestion time, but a lot of the value of ingestionTime are the same, maybe all these were inserted by a batch script. And I checked that there is no row policy on my table.

Comment: I find a strange behavior, If I use the same data source and execute the same query containing arg_max, the result is not the same. 178 data out of 1090000 are different.

Comment: Which result do you want to see output?  The first occurrence or last?  Ingestion time could be the same if it's as you say you have a batch import.  Otherwise KQL should be taking the first row it finds (but sorry can't find anything referring to this functionality in the docs).

Comment: I couldn't find the official document mentioned this. But I learned a lot from your answer. Thanks.